# snap page when vertical scrolling to the next section

Tags: jquery, navigation, scrollto, slidedown, vertical-scroll

Hi I know there's a few other posts on this topic, but none of them seem to have a clear solid answer.

I'm trying to recreate the effect on this website using jquery:

http://beoplay.com/Support

The simplest method for the single page navigation with slides for each page seems to be  jqueryTools:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/site-navigation.html

How would I add the effect to "snap" to the same sections on the page as the side navigation when scrolling down with the mouse, so everything you want to see is in viewport? Almost like they are individual slides...

Other posts suggested impress.js, stellar.js, and waypoints, but none of these seem to work all that great for this effect alone and I'd rather not use another plugin.

I think with something like "scroll(), scrollTo(), jumpScroll", this can be achieved easily.

And here are two very similar posts, but none of the answers seem to work that well:

11051650

10171058